# How to mock a function on a service that will return a rejected promise?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm using Angular 6 with Jasmine to test my code.

I have a function that calls a service to log in, the service returns a promise that will reject or resolve based on whether the log in was successful or not.

I don't want the actual service function to run so I've been trying to mock it, all I want it to do is return a promise that will reject but I can't figure out the syntax. I've already searched for hours but nothing works, this eventuality doesn't seem to be covered anywhere.

Can anyone provide an example of how you would mock a service function to provide a promise that will reject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mock function, you do: `return Promise.reject(your value)`.

It will create a `Promise` that will reject directly when queried.

**Edit from your comment**:

So if you use Jasmine facilities, you can use `mockLoginService.login.and.returnValue(Promise.reject())` to get the mocking capability and reject the login attempt.

Comment: I am using `mockLoginService.login.and.returnValue()` where would your answer fit in here, or doesn't it?

Comment: `mockLoginService.login.and.returnValue(Promise.reject())` works perfectly!  Would you edit your answer to include this or some version of this as the exact syntax is near impossible to find online